# Mapping key bindings

Tags: x11, keyboard, key-mapping

Background: I got an Acer Chromebook yesterday and I am running Ubuntu on it (I am also somewhat new to Linux). The keyboard does not have dedicated <kbd>Home</kbd> and <kbd>End</kbd> buttons since in ChromeOS there are replacement key bindings (that do not work under the running Linux).

My question: is if there is a way to assign certain key binding in Linux to <kbd>Home</kbd> and <kbd>End</kbd> key actions so that I can recover those two keys by key combinations.

Comment: Which key combination would you prefer to assign to `Home` and `End`? If it's a combination with modifiers, there's an added difficulty in not transmitting the modifiers to the application.

Comment: The ChromeOS combinates are ctrl+alt+up/down for [home] and [end] -I think. And there is not much room to spare on the keuboard, so I guess I am looking for something with the modifiers, if possible.

Answer (score 4):

In [xkeyboard-config-1.7-nav-keys.patch](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromiumos/overlays/chromiumos-overlay/+/22904dac59dbf9c0d29ae452786ee94d6bf1e4b2/x11-misc/xkeyboard-config/files/xkeyboard-config-1.7-nav-keys.patch) is explained how it used to be done, with XKB. More recent versions of Chrome OS [now use Ash](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=213609).

Create directories called `~/.xkb/keymap`, `~/.xkb/types` and `~/.xkb/symbols`. Create a file `~/.xkb/types/chromebook` containing the following definition:

```
xkb_types "chromebook" {
    virtual_modifiers Alt;
    type "ARROW" {
        modifiers              = Shift+Lock+Alt+Control;
        map[Shift]             = Level2;
        map[Lock]              = Level2;
        map[Alt]               = Level3;
        map[Alt+Shift]         = Level3;
        map[Alt+Lock]          = Level3;
        map[Control+Alt]       = Level4;
        map[Control+Alt+Shift] = Level4;
        map[Control+Alt+Lock]  = Level4;
        level_name[Level1]     = "Base";
        level_name[Level2]     = "Caps";
        level_name[Level3]     = "Alt";
        level_name[Level4]     = "ControlAlt";
    };
}
```

Create a file `~/.xkb/symbols/chromebook` containing the following definition:

```
xkb_symbols "chromebook" {
    key <UP> {
        type="ARROW",
        repeat=yes,
        [ Up, Up, Prior, Home ],
        actions[Group1] = [
            NoAction(),
            NoAction(),
            RedirectKey(key=<PGUP>, clearmods=Alt),
            RedirectKey(key=<HOME>, clearmods=Control+Alt)
        ]
    };
    key <DOWN> {
        type="ARROW",
        repeat=yes,
        [ Down, Down, Next, End ],
        actions[Group1] = [
            NoAction(),
            NoAction(),
            RedirectKey(key=<PGDN>, clearmods=Alt),
            RedirectKey(key=<END>, clearmods=Control+Alt)
        ]
    };
};
```

Run the command `setxkbmap -print >~/.xkb/keymap/chromebook`. Edit the resulting file and add `+chromebook` inside the `include` directives for `xkb_types` and `xkb_symbols`; the file should look like this:

```
xkb_keymap {
        xkb_keycodes  { include "evdev+aliases(qwerty)" };
        xkb_types     { include "complete+chromebook"      };
        xkb_compat    { include "complete"      };
        xkb_symbols   { include "pc+us+inet(evdev)+chromebook"     };
        xkb_geometry  { include "pc(pc105)"     };
};
```

Add the following command to the [startup applications](https://askubuntu.com/questions/30931/how-do-i-make-a-program-auto-start-every-time-i-log-in):

```
xkbcomp -I ~/.xkb -R ~/.xkb keymap/chromebook $DISPLAY
```

Note: this is untested, I'm not very familiar with XKB and it's poorly documented. I tried to follow [Vincent Lefèvre's XKB tips](http://www.vinc17.org/unix/xkb.en.html).