# Change the status of the keyboard leds, from within an X session, without root access

Tags: linux, x11, xorg, io-redirection, console

I am trying to force the capslock led on. `xset` does not work for me, so I am trying to use `setleds`.

In a graphical console, this command returns:

```
> LANG=C setleds -L +caps
KDGKBLED: Inappropriate ioctl for device
Error reading current flags setting. Maybe you are not on the console?
```

In a virtual terminal, it works, however the effect is local to that virtual terminal. From what I understand, running

```
> setleds -L +caps < /dev/tty1
```

from a virtual terminal (my X server is sitting on tty1) should work. However, this requires root access.

Is there a way to send a command to the console underlying a X server, be it from the said xserver or from another VT, without root?

Edit: From a suggestion from Mark Plotnik, and based on code found [here](https://logixoul.wordpress.com/2008/08/14/how-to-set-leds-in-x-even-on-ubuntu/), I wrote and compiled the following:

```
#include <X11/Xlib.h>
#include <X11/XKBlib.h>

#define SCROLLLOCK 1
#define CAPSLOCK 2
#define NUMLOCK 16

void setLeds(int leds) {
   Display *dpy = XOpenDisplay(0);
   XKeyboardControl values;
   values.led_mode = leds & SCROLLLOCK ? LedModeOn : LedModeOff;
   values.led = 3;
   XChangeKeyboardControl(dpy, KBLedMode, &values);
   XkbLockModifiers(dpy, XkbUseCoreKbd, CAPSLOCK | NUMLOCK,
                    leds & (CAPSLOCK | NUMLOCK) );
   XFlush(dpy);
   XCloseDisplay(dpy);
}

int main() {
   setLeds(CAPSLOCK);
   return 0;
}
```

From what Gilles wrote about `xset`, I did not expect it to work, but it does... in some sense: it sets the led, but it also sets the capslock status. I do not fully understand all the code above, so I may have done a silly mistake. Apparently, the line `XChangeKeyboardControl...` does not change the behavior of the program, and `XkbLockModifiers` is what sets the led and the capslock status.

Comment: You can do something like `xdotool key Caps_Lock` from an authorized X client, although this will actually turn on caps lock.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick The point is indeed not to turn CapsLock on. Is there a way to turn CapsLock off, without touching the led?

Comment: I looked at the `xterm` source, and it uses a call to [XChangeKeyboardControl()](http://www.x.org/archive/current/doc/man/man3/XChangeKeyboardControl.3.xhtml) to set or unset the LEDs without affecting the state of caps lock etc. So if you can compile C code, that's one approach.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick Does `xterm` affect the leds? It sounds like a good idea, I will edit the question with my results.

Comment: I got `xterm` to light up ScrollLock LED by sending the escape sequence ESC [ 3 q , as per the file `ctlseqs.txt` that comes with the source, but couldn't get the Num or CapsLock LEDs to light up with parameters 1 and 2. Maybe I need to do the XKB configuration mentioned in the answer. `xterm` calls `XChangeKeyboardControl` in `xtermShowLED` and `xtermClearLEDs`, but doesn't call `XkbLockModifiers` anywhere at all.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In principle, you should be able to do it with the venerable [`xset`](http://www.x.org/archive/X11R7.5/doc/man/man1/xset.1.html) command.

```
xset led named 'Caps Lock'
```

or `xset led 4` to set LED number 4, if your system doesn't recognize the LEDs by name.

However, this doesn't seem to work reliably. On my machine, I can only set Scroll Lock this way, and [I'm not the only one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7701398/how-do-i-light-up-the-caps-lock-light-with-xset). This [seems to be a matter of XKB configuration](https://www.libreoffice.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=49276).

The following user-level work-around should work (for the most part):

1. Extract your current xkb configuration:

   ```
   xkbcomp $DISPLAY myconf.xkb
   ```
2. Edit the file `myconf.xkb`, replacing `!allowExplicit` with `allowExplicit` in the relevant blocks:

   ```
   indicator "Caps Lock" {
       allowExplicit;
       whichModState= locked;
       modifiers= Lock;
   };
   indicator "Num Lock" {
       allowExplicit;
       whichModState= locked;
       modifiers= NumLock;
   };
   ```
3. Load the new file

   ```
   xkbcomp myconf.xkb $DISPLAY
   ```

Now setting the leds on and off with `xset` should work. According to the bug report, you will not be able to switch the leds off when they are supposed to be on (for example if CapsLock is enabled).

Comment: Thanks! I had tried `xset` before, and indeed it does not work. I had not seen this bug report though. Anyway, "Status: Resolved Wontfix" is not really encouraging... The `allowExplicit` work-around would probably work for me (I don't need to turn the led off), but changing it still requires root.

Comment: @T.Verron You don't need to be root to change the XKB configuration. You can call `xkbcomp` at any time. I'm not familiar enough with XKB to tell you exactly what you need to change (setting a specific aspect rather than a full predefined map with XKB is a bit of a pain), but http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/166844/mapping-key-bindings/166913#166913 should have a few pointers.

Comment: Oh, good point. Well, as a first attempt, I tried: `xkbcomp $DISPLAY output.xkb`, then replacing `!allowExplicit` by `allowExplicit` in the `indicator "Caps Lock"` section, then reloading the file with `xkbcomp output.xkb`. There is a lot of warnings, and xset doesn't work any better afterwards. I will read some more about xkb.

Comment: This kind of worked for me. After I imported the modified file I got some error messages and I could light the LEDs but other things got messed up, plus it did not survive a restart. So I went ahead an edited `/usr/share/X11/xkb/compat/ledcaps` and .../lednum and this made it permanent.

Answer (score 2):

## Using `sed`

```
$ sudo sed -i 's|\!allowExplicit|allowExplicit|g' /usr/share/X11/xkb/compat/ledcaps
```

After logging out and in again, the <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> LED can now be controlled without any `root` privileges using the commands:

```
$ xset led named 'Caps Lock'
$ xset -led named 'Caps Lock'
```

Comment: But this requires root.

Comment: @T.Verron Only once to change a configuration file with `sudo` and then never again. To gain an understanding why this might be so important to certain users, see this [`vim` application](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/17824/3168).

Comment: Being the one who asked the question 3 years ago, I definitely understand why it can be important to some users (in my case, it was to work around the stupid delay apple keyboards have when activating capslock, after remapping capslock to control). But back then, I specifically needed a solution without any root access at all, because it was for a work computer. The accepted answer involves a few more steps, but it does work without sudo.

Comment: @T.Verron I understand. Shared systems are another case where this would not work. Notwithstanding, I liked the straightforwardness of the last commenter on the accepted answer and made a `sed` one-liner out of it.

Answer (score 0):

A combination of the root-less approach by @Gilles with the idea of full automation by @Serge_Stroobandt.

To enable control of the *Caps Lock*, *Num Lock* and *Shift Lock* LEDs:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Enables to control keyboard LEDs that are not available for control by default
xkbcomp $DISPLAY /tmp/my_conf.xkb
cat /tmp/my_conf.xkb | awk -e '
    BEGIN {
        change = 0
    }

    {
        if (change == 1) {
            if ($1 == "!allowExplicit;") {
                gsub("!", "", $0)
            }
            change = 0
        }
        print $0

    }

    /indicator "Caps Lock"/ {
        change = 1
    }
    /indicator "Num Lock"/ {
        change = 1
    }
    /indicator "Shift Lock"/ {
        change = 1
    }
    ' > /tmp/my_conf_modified.xkb
xkbcomp /tmp/my_conf_modified.xkb $DISPLAY
```

To turn a LED on and off:

```
# Turns the LED on
xset led named 'Caps Lock'

# wait 1s
sleep 1

# Resets the LED to the actual state,
# so it might still be on, if Caps Lock is activated.
xset -led named 'Caps Lock'
```