# How to identify if Num lock or Caps lock is turned on in RHEL 6.6?

Tags: gui

My Thinkpad T430 has no visible indicator if a num lock/caps lock is on/off is there a way to notify on screen when turned on/off?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can try getting info with [xset](http://www.x.org/archive/X11R7.5/doc/man/man1/xset.1.html):

```
xset q | grep Caps
```

Result:

```
00: Caps Lock:   off    01: Num Lock:    on     02: Scroll Lock: off
```

But if no X you can try [kbdinfo](http://man.sourcentral.org/f21/1+kbdinfo):

```
kbdinfo gkbled
```

Result:

```
scrolllock:off numlock:on capslock:off
```

Edit:
If you want to change states with `xset` you may check following [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/179286/change-the-status-of-the-keyboard-leds-from-within-an-x-session-without-root-a).

Or you can change state using [xdotool](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/xdotool.1.html):

```
xdotool key Caps_Lock
```

For onscreen notifier you may check [key-mon](https://code.google.com/p/key-mon/).

You can try also following script:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
#lockkey.sh

sleep .2

case $1 in
    'num')
        mask=2
        key="Num"
        ;;
    'caps')
        mask=1
        key="Caps"
        ;;
esac

value="$(xset q | grep 'LED mask' | awk '{ print $NF }')"

if [ $(( 0x$value & 0x$mask )) == $mask ]
then
    output="$key Lock is on"
else
    output="$key Lock is off"
fi

notify-send "$output"
```

You can copy script in `/usr/local/bin` and bind <kbd>Caps</kbd> to run it as:

```
/usr/local/bin/lockkey.sh caps
```

and/or <kbd>Num</kbd> as:

```
/usr/local/bin/lockkey.sh num
```

Comment: i have xset, but how do i change the value for Caps Lock?

Comment: @user115806 I added link to answer for changing state of Caps Lock. But in your question you want only to check states.

Comment: that's a very well written answer. I'll rephrase my question and my T430 doesn't have LED's to indicate its on/off so i thought if there's a way to notify on screen when caps lock is pressed. I also came across "notify-send" is there a way when i press caps lock and it shows up on my screen.?

Comment: @taliezin how to bind Caps to the script? found this http://askubuntu.com/questions/15050/how-do-i-bind-sh-files-to-keyboard-combination used Compiz Config Settings Manager to bind the CapsLock key placed your script as CustomScript.sh in /usr/local/bin and did Chmod+x CustomScript.sh it didn't work :(

Comment: Can you try first running script from command line: CustomScript.sh caps ?

Comment: in Terminal - 
[rahul@345 bin]$ sh CustomScript.sh 
CustomScript.sh: line 19: [: 0: unary operator expected
[rahul@345 bin]$ 

there was a notification on screen as  "Lock is off".

Pressed Capslock key and ran the script again same notification on screen "Lock is off"

Comment: You have to put argument after script: "caps" or "num", e.g: CustomScript.sh caps

Comment: Bingo! it worked. Oh i get it..$key has the value of parameter passed to script.

Comment: @taliezin xdotool didn't work properly once i change that code in myconf.xkb `!allowexplicit` to `allowexplict` i get lot of errors can't proceed further. any other solution?

Comment: You can post another question because I don't understand you.

Comment: ok. I was referring to [this] answer (http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/179378/117312). on how to change the state with xset.

Answer (score 1):

The T430 may have no CapsLock LED, but the Power LED can be SW controlled (tested with Linux kernel 4.2) and thus abused nicely. First add this to your /etc/rc.local:

```
echo kbd-capslock >/sys/class/leds/tpacpi::power/trigger
chmod 666 /sys/class/leds/tpacpi::power/brightness
```

The 1st line takes care of the text console and, as a side effect, turns the LED off initially. To handle X11 the 2nd line permits normal users to control the LED. Then save this code

```
#!/bin/sh
sleep 0.1
if xset q | grep -q 'Caps Lock: *on'; then
    echo 255 >/sys/class/leds/tpacpi::power/brightness
else
    echo 0 >/sys/class/leds/tpacpi::power/brightness
fi
```

as some executable script (e.g. /usr/local/bin/capsled.sh) and in your Desktop settings bind the CapsLock key to run it. Ugly as hell but works (tested with XFCE4). Does anyone know a cleaner way to remap the LED under X11?

Answer (score -1):

```
CAPS_STATUS=`xset q | grep -i caps | cut -c 22-24`
#test on $CAPS_STATUS if its on or off
```