# In X11, how can I create a custom key combination that maps to PgUp, PgDn, Home, and End?

Tags: x11, keyboard-shortcuts

My keyboard does not have keys for <kbd>Home</kbd>, <kbd>End</kbd>, <kbd>Page Up</kbd>, and <kbd>Page Down</kbd>. I would like do the following:

- Map <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>⇦</kbd> to <kbd>Home</kbd>
- Map <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>⇨</kbd> to <kbd>End</kbd>
- Map <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>⇧</kbd> to <kbd>Page Up</kbd>
- Map <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>⇩</kbd> to <kbd>Page Down</kbd>

I've tried using Gnome's custom keyboard shortcuts with `xdotool`, however it doesn't seem to work with `xdotool`.

Comment: You'll have to look into `xkb`. The answer [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/166844) might be a good starting point.