# Where do I edit the keyboard "system settings" these days?

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout, xkb, defaults

The last time I manually edited keyboard settings was sometime last decade. There days it looks like things have have changed. Now, when I use the Keyboard layouts dialog in XFCE or LXDE, I can either make 'manual' settings via the dialog, or "Keep System Settings". So,

- Where are those system settings?
- How do I print them out (as opposed to `setxkbmap -print` for what I have right now)?
- How do I edit them?

**Note:** I'm using Debian based distributions, mainly Debian Stretch and Kubuntu 14.04, but I hope the answers will not need to be that specific.

Answer (score 0):

You should:

1. Extract your current `xkb` configuration:

   ```
   xkbcomp $DISPLAY myconf.xkb
   ```
2. Now you can read/edit your configuration in your favorite text editor.
3. Save your configuration:

   ```
   xkbcomp myconf.xkb $DISPLAY
   ```

Comment: Ok, I'll try that. But - where is that configuration extracted from? It's not some evil systemd binary blob somewhere is it?

Comment: Its just a Text file. Here is a Post of someone who asked a similar question: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/166844/mapping-key-bindings/166913#166913

Comment: Okay, it's a supr-explicit 2000-line file. I was hoping for something along the lines of `ledscroll(group_lock)` and `group(alt_shift_toggle)` etc which I would be adding in or removing.